# Grails Neo4J Plugin Documentation

Tags: grails, neo4j

Last time I looked at Neo4j plugin for grails it was under heavy development towards 2.x version. 
As of now, it looks like the available version is: 2.0.0-M02: http://grails.org/plugin/neo4j
However, linked documentation at http://projects.spring.io/grails-data-mapping/neo4j/index.html is still for 1.0.0 and it looks outdated.
Where can I find proper docs for the currently available version?

Thanks,